# ¿Por que no funciona el query designer en mi reporte?

Tags: java, sql, ireport

apenas empecé a ver sobre este tema sin embargo el curso que estoy tomando es algo viejo, tuve que descargar el plugin de iReport de manera diferente. Aun así  todo iba bien hasta este punto donde necesito utilizar este botón(query designer). Le doy click y no pasa nada, todos los demás botones funcionan excepto por ese. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
la versión que tengo de java es la 12.6, y ya cerré y volví a abrir java y nada.

Comment: ¿iReport es compatible con Java 12? Lo dudo, honestamente. iReport hace un buen tiempo fue reemplazado por JasperReports.

Comment: Estimada @padaleiana, sólo precisar que fue reemplazado por *Jaspersoft Studio*, y que *JasperReports* es la librería subyacente en ambos.

Comment: El datasource *Reporte* ¿es una conexión JDBC?

Comment: si, lo es. Pero entonces esta mal mi librería?

Comment: No necesariamente, prueba con Java 7; por que el cambio a 
*JasperSoft Studio* es lo suficiente como para que no te sirva el material del curso. Realmente casi no hubo cambio respecto a la estructura del jrxml, por si mucho en la GUI.

Comment: @Sal es verdad, agradecida.